# GWT MaterialDataTable handle Resize and Horizontal Scroll

Tags: java, gwt

on first loadData scrollbar horizontal is visible an working
but as soon as i hit search again to load data + the scroller is hidden invisible (is there some way to always display scrollbars ?)

[image]

if i resize the window scrollbar returns to be visible

the Table is in

```
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <m:MaterialPanel>
            <m:table.MaterialDataTable ui:field="table" shadow="1" height="440px"/>
        </m:MaterialPanel>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
```

And the resize 100% Code

```
    private void continuousAdaptTableHeight() {
    Timer t = new Timer() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isInDialog()){
                Integer windowHeight=getMaterialWindow().asWidget().getElement().getClientHeight();
                Integer tableAbsoluteTop = genericListPresenter.getTable().asWidget().getElement().getAbsoluteTop();
                Integer newTableHeight = windowHeight - tableAbsoluteTop-40;
                genericListPresenter.getTable().setHeight(newTableHeight + "px");
            }
            else{
                Integer tableAbsoluteTop = genericListPresenter.getTable().asWidget().getElement().getAbsoluteTop();
                Integer windowHeight= Window.getClientHeight();
                Integer newTableHeight = windowHeight - tableAbsoluteTop-100;
                genericListPresenter.getTable().setHeight(newTableHeight + "px");
            }


        }

    };
    t.scheduleRepeating(200);
}
```

Comment: When the scrollbar is invisible, when you hover over where it should be, does it appear?

Comment: @RobertNewton no scrollbar